# How to install Nvidia driver on ubuntu

Tags: nvidia

I have nvidia GTX 930M and can't setup own driver. please help me step by step to install driver. my ubuntu version is 17.04.

Comment: Did you try this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Wait at least one minute for the command to scan your computer and generate the list of drivers. The output of this command will be a list of the package names and short descriptions of the available drivers. In addition to showing a list of the available drivers, the above command will often also identify the recommended proprietary driver(s) for your system.

Install the recommended proprietary NVIDIA driver. If the name of the recommended proprietary NVIDIA driver is, for example, "nvidia-example-driver" install it using the following commands:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-example-driver # replace nvidia-example-driver with the name of the recommended driver 
sudo reboot
```

You can install the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver alongside the built-in open source nouveau graphics driver. If the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver has a problem and Ubuntu can't boot, Ubuntu will try to boot using the nouveau driver as a fallback graphics driver.

Comment: Don't know why, but worked for me !